# Highlighting lines that contain a phrase using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm highlighting lines that contain a certain phrase using regex.

My current highlight function will read the whole text and place every instance of the phrase within a highlight span.

```
    const START = "<span name='highlight' style='background-color: yellow;'>";
    const END   = "</span>"

    function highlight(text, toReplace) {

        let reg = new RegExp(toReplace, 'ig');

        return text.replace(reg, START + toReplace + END);
    }
```

I want to expand my regex so that, for each phrase, it highlights from the preceding `<br>` to the following `<br>`.

`highlight("This<br>is some text to<br>highlight.", "text");`

Current output:

```
This<br>is some<span name="highlight" style="background-color:yellow;">text</span> to<br>highlight."
```

Wanted output:

```
This<br><span name="highlight" style="background-color:yellow;">is some text to</span><br>highlight.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to match all chars other than `<` and `>` before and after the `text` and it is advisable to escape the literal text you pass to the `RegExp` constructor. Also, to replace with the whole match, just use `$&` placeholder:

```js
const START = "<span name='highlight' style='background-color: yellow;'>";
const END   = "</span>"

function highlight(text, toReplace) {
   let reg = new RegExp("(<br/?>)|[^<>]*" + toReplace.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') + "[^<>]*", 'ig');
   return text.replace(reg, function ($0,$1) { return $1 ? $1 : START + $0 + END; });
}
console.log(highlight("This<br>is some text to<br>highlight.", "text"));

console.log(highlight("This<br>is a bunch of<br>text", "b"));
```

The regex will look like `/[^<>]*text[^<>]*/gi`, it will match 0 or more chars other than `<` and `>`, then `text` in a case insensitive way and then again 0 or more chars other than `<` and `>`, and the `$&` in the replacement will put the matched value into the highlighting tags.

Comment: This is almost perfect! However, it breaks on the edge case of highlighting ```"<br>"``` or any subset of that (```"<"```, ```"r"```, ```"br"```, etc). Is there a possible fix? I won't know ahead of time what's being highlighted.

Comment: @MichaelBianconi Please provide a sample `highlight(...,...)` to showcase the issue.

Comment: highlight("This<br>is a bunch of text to<br>highlight.", "b")

Comment: @MichaelBianconi That is already another question. Do you want to match a`text` as a whole word? Then use word boundaries (`new RegExp("[^<>]*\\b" + toReplace.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') + "\\b[^<>]*", 'ig')`) or unambiguous word boundaries (`new RegExp("[^<>]*(?:^|\\W)" + toReplace.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') + "(?!\\w)[^<>]*", 'ig')`) or whitespace boundaries (`new RegExp("[^<>]*(?:^|\\s)" + toReplace.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') + "(?!\\S)[^<>]*", 'ig')`). I do not know your actual requirements, nor possible input.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by word boundaries. Assume that possible input can be all kinds of funky stuff. It's procedurally-generated and it can be a little wonky at times. I need ```highlight()``` to not start or stop highlighting in the middle of a ```<br>``` (e.g. ```This<<span...>br> is a bunch of</span><br>text```. This happens when the user tries to highlight a substring of ```<br>```.

Comment: @MichaelBianconi Do you want to 1) cancel a match in between `<` and `>`, 2) avoid matching the literal `<br>` string?

Comment: I want to cancel any matches within the ```<br>```, but not outside. For ```highlight("This<br>is a bunch of<br>text", "b") = "This<br><span...>is a bunch of</span><br>text"```

Comment: @MichaelBianconi Updated the answer to avoid matching inside `<br>` and  `<br/>`

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this simple expression,

```
(<br>)(.*?)(\1)
```

might work here.

```js
const regex = /(<br>)(.*?)(\1)/gs;
const str = `This<br>is some text to<br>highlight. This<br>is some text to<br>highlight.  This<br>is some text to<br>highlight.  


This<br>is some 

text to<br>highlight. This<br>is some text to<br>highlight.  This<br>is some text to<br>highlight.`;
const subst = `$1<span name='highlight' style='background-color: yellow;'>$2</span>$3`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

In this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/UDMQJ6/1/), the expression is explained, if you might be interested.