# Highlight Every Instance of String in <div> - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have seen multiple posts on here finding and highlighting strings but none have worked as expected yet. Below is my script currently:

```
var str = 'word';
var divs= document.getElementsByClassName('strings');
for (var i = 0, len = divs.length; i < len; ++i) {
    if(divs[i].innerHTML.indexOf(str) !== -1) {
        // something
        console.log('YES');
        str.replace(/(\w+) (\w+)/, '<div class="strings">$1</div> <div class="strings">$2</div>');
    }else{
        console.log('NO');
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="strings">word word words</div>
```

Ideally this would highlight every instance of the string in my `div` each time the `js` is run as a function.

Comment: Take a look at this question I asked a while back https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56773386/highlighting-lines-that-contain-a-phrase-using-regex

Comment: What is your expected output? What do you mean by "highlighting"? Adding CSS, adding `<mark>` tags? Your code is attempting to create a `<div></span>` element which is likely a typo. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @ggorlen it was a typo thank you, as for my desired output Im not 100% sure. End goal is to have a search form that each time it changes the `js` function runs and highlights (with css or anything) the string entered yellow. Changing the `background-color` would probably be the easiest route

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show how this question differs from any of the others one can find with [a simple search of this site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Highlight+Every+Instance+of+String+%5Bjavascript%5D).

Comment: Give this a look too... looks like you're pretty close: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32130293/682232

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted is on the right track and regex replace is convenient, but be very careful that, in addition to using the correct logic, you're not opening yourself up to [XSS attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) or regex escaping problems by sanitizing your input field (although the XSS issue would be mainly problematic if the user supplies the target/source text).

Use the `"gi"` flags on the regex to make your search case-insensitive (I used a checkbox to toggle), and feel free to loop over multiple text areas you'd like to search when updating (I left it as one for simplicity). Add `\b` to the regex to enforce strict word boundaries (also toggleable in the below example). You can also use basically any element or styling on your highlighted element. `<mark>` seems most semantic.

Lastly, it's worth ensuring that the search term doesn't consist of an empty string, which would add a lot of garbage highlight tags between every character of the text.

```js
const escapeHTML = html => {
  const ta = document.createElement("textarea");
  ta.textContent = html;
  return ta.innerHTML;
};

const escapeRegex = s => s.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
  
const highlight = (searchTerm, originalText, caseIns, boundaries) => {
  const pattern = boundaries ? `(\\b${searchTerm}\\b)` : `(${searchTerm})`;
  return searchTerm ? originalText.replace(
    RegExp(pattern, "g" + (caseIns ? "i" : "")), "<mark>$1</mark>"
  ) : originalText;
};

const output = document.querySelector("#output");
const originalText = output.innerText;
let caseIns = false;
let boundaries = false;
let searchTerm = "";

document.querySelector("#ignore-case").addEventListener("change", e => { 
  caseIns = e.target.checked; 
  output.innerHTML = highlight(searchTerm, originalText, caseIns, boundaries);
});
document.querySelector("#word-boundaries").addEventListener("change", e => { 
  boundaries = e.target.checked; 
  output.innerHTML = highlight(searchTerm, originalText, caseIns, boundaries);
});
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("keyup", e => {
  searchTerm = escapeHTML(escapeRegex(e.target.value));
  output.innerHTML = highlight(searchTerm, originalText, caseIns, boundaries);
});
```

```css
div:first-child {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

span {
  margin-left: 1em;
}

mark { /* add styling here */
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input placeholder="search term" />
  <span>Ignore case? <input type="checkbox" id="ignore-case" /></span>
  <span>Word boundaries? <input type="checkbox" id="word-boundaries" /></span>
</div>
<div id="output">Fourscore and seven years ago our fathers brought forth, on this continent, a new nation, conceived in liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal. Now we are engaged in a great civil war, testing whether that nation, or any nation so conceived, and so dedicated, can long endure. We are met on a great battle-field of that war. We have come to dedicate a portion of that field, as a final resting-place for those who here gave their lives, that that nation might live. It is altogether fitting and proper that we should do this. But, in a larger sense, we cannot dedicate, we cannot consecrate—we cannot hallow—this ground. The brave men, living and dead, who struggled here, have consecrated it far above our poor power to add or detract. The world will little note, nor long remember what we say here, but it can never forget what they did here. It is for us the living, rather, to be dedicated here to the unfinished work which they who fought here have thus far so nobly advanced. It is rather for us to be here dedicated to the great task remaining before us—that from these honored dead we take increased devotion to that cause for which they here gave the last full measure of devotion—that we here highly resolve that these dead shall not have died in vain—that this nation, under God, shall have a new birth of freedom, and that government of the people, by the people, for the people, shall not perish from the earth.</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `replace()` method on the needle and not on the hay stack. You want to find the str in the `innerHTML` attribute and then replace the innerHTML attribute with a copy that is surrounding the given `str` found with `' tags.

Because you're using a variable for the regex search you need to first make a regex object and inject the needle string into it. also give it the `g` flag so it matches every instance of the found regex:

```
var regex = new RegExp(`${str}`, ['g']);
```

Then you manipulate the innerHTML attribute of the div element:

```
divs[i].innerHTML = divs[i].innerHTML.replace(regex, `<span class"highlighted">${str}</span>`);
```

Now the script will look for the word and wrap it a span with `.highlighted` class.
So now all that's left to do is fix the css to handle it:

```
.highlighted {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```